# Python Reportlab Latin characters encoding

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, reportlab

How would you manage certain latin characters (č, ć, ž, š, đ) in reportlab? Tried various types of UTF-8 encoding, but without luck. It displays as unreadable streams of data.

Can anyone help? Also, I changed fonts multiple times, but also without success.

This is part of PDF where I'm getting problem -

[image]

and this is my part of code (beside that, OpenSans font is set that supports letters like š, ć, č, ž, đ):

```
data2 = [[ Paragraph(cell, styleN)  if cell.isascii() and cell.isprintable() else Paragraph(cell.encode('utf-8'), styleN)  for cell in row] for row in array]
        t = Table(data2, colWidths=[None] + [2.2*inch] + [1.3 * inch]*int(len(json.loads(request.POST['kolone'])) - 2 ), rowHeights= [None] + [0.5*inch] + [None] * int(len(array) -2), repeatRows=1)
        t.setStyle(TableStyle([('TEXTCOLOR',(1,1),(-2,-2), "black"),  ('FONTSIZE', (0,0),(-1,-1), 9), ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,0), 0.25, 'black'), ('PADDING', (0,0),(-1,-1), 2), ('VALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'TOP')]))
```

As you can see, I tried to delimit all records that have "special character" and encode them.

Comment: With this little detail it's pretty much impossible to tell whether there is an error in your code or a bug in `reportlab` or something else. So please share some code. Also, a sample of the "stream of unreadable characters" might give helpful clues.

Comment: I hope you can see now the problem. Please reffer to this picture and part of code, I will add more if you need